# Как правильно создавать пользовательские атрибуты в html5

Tags: html, html5

Гугл мне не дал однозначного ответа из-за даты статей и хелпов, которые я смог найти.
Но все же - как сейчас принято создавать пользовательские атрибуты ( от одного до много ) в html5 тегах?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Принято хранить с префиксом `data-*`.